# Regex: Parse specific string with one 18-digit number

Tags: c#, .net, regex, parsing

C#/.NET 4.0

I need to parse a string containing a 18-digit number. I also need the substrings at the left and right side.
Example strings:

```
string a = "Frl Camp Gerbesklooster 871687120000000691 OPLDN 2010 H1";
string b = "some text with spaces 123456789012345678 more text";
```

How it should be parsed:

```
string aParsed[0] = "Frl Camp Gerbesklooster";
string aParsed[1] = "871687120000000691";
string aParsed[2] = "OPLDN 2010 H1";

string bParsed[0] = "some text with spaces";
string bParsed[1] = "123456789012345678";
string bParsed[2] = "more text";
```

There is always that 18-digit number in the middle of the string. I'm an absolute newbie to Regex so I don't actually have a try of my own.
What is the best way to do this? Should I use regular expressions?
Thanks.

Comment: Can the string contain another 18-digit number?

Comment: "I don't actually have a try of my own". I suggest you start learning - what you are asking for is rather basic, so would be a good intro to regex.

Comment: @m0skit0 no, just one 18-digit number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like the regex: `(.*)(\d{18})(.*)`.

The key here is to use `{18}` to specify that there must be exactly `18` digits and to capture each part in a group.

```
var parts = Regex.Matches(s, @"(.*)(\d{18})(.*)")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .SelectMany(m => m.Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1).Select(g=>g.Value))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, just can't get it to work. I tried `Regex.Split()` and `Regex.Match()` and Google doesn't give me the right samples. Could you post some C# code?

Comment: @L.B - Thanks a lot. I am not a C# developer and I didn't know you can use it in this functional style.

Comment: @L.B Thanks a lot! I would never have found that.

Answer (score 0):

Daniël,

Although the question is answered the following may be a useful reference for learning Reg Expressions.

http://txt2re.com

Regards,
Liam